# Protocol downcasting in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following situation where I have a generic protocol `A` that can have variants that inherit from it (e.g. `B`) and a class that implements a variant (`C`).

```
protocol A {}

protocol B: A {
  var foo: String { get }
}

class C: B {
  let foo: String = "foo"
}
```

Now, if I have an object of type `A`, but is actually a `C`, how can I get to stuff declared in `B`?

```
func foo() {
  let c: A = C()
}
```

If I try to cast as in `let b = c as B` I get `Cannot downcast from 'A' to non-@objc protocol type 'B'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks good - the only problem is that the `as` operator requires objc compatibility. You can fix it by prefixing your protocols with the @objc attribute:

```
@objc protocol A {}

@objc protocol B: A {
    var foo: String { get }
}
```

Unfortunately there's a downside on doing that: you lose the ability to use swift-specific features that are not available in objective C, such as enums, tuples, generics, etc.

More info here: [Checking for Protocol Conformance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_426)

Comment: Bugger, looking forward to @objc dying. Thanks!

Comment: Added link to the documentation, where that is explained - if interested